# Bootstrap left and right margin to the edge of an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have an image inside the container with left and right margins removed:

**css:**

```
.container{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

  .full-size{
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

**html:**

```
<div id="content" class="container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <img class="img-responsive full-size" src="http://placehold.it/900x500">
</div>
```

demo: http://www.bootply.com/0ElBn1DBBU

but I can't get the image to be full size and 0 margins. The image goes to the left but not full width.

Answer (score 1):

The padding of the container class is limiting it. I would make a seperate class called image-container and wrap the image with that. Then the margins will have an effect.
`<div class="image-container">
    <img class="img-responsive full-size" src="http://placehold.it/900x500">
</div>`

`.image-container{
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}`

See here for an example. 
http://www.bootply.com/661aOu5SKh

If you wanted to also remove the bottom padding, add `margin-bottom: -20px;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `padding: 20px;` on the `.container` class with `padding: 0;` and remove `margin-left: -20px;` and `margin-right: -20px;` from `.full-size` class.

Here is what the CSS looks like after these modifications:

```
  .container{
      /*padding: 20px;*/
      background-color: #eee;
      max-width: 600px;
      min-height: 500px;
      margin: 20px auto;

      padding: 0;
  }
```

And:

```
  .full-size{
      /*margin-left: -20px;*/
      /*margin-right: -20px;*/
      width: 100%;
  }
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/Yuz0rsCbLV

Answer (score 0):

The 20px padding on your container is causing all the grief. If you remove that from the container class, you don't need any full-size class at all. To improve the look of the text add padding to the p tag inside the container:

```
.container{
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.container p {
  padding: 20px;
}

.full-size{

}
```